# Why did the ancient Romans kill deer so often?

Tags: ancient-history, food, greece, rome

I've heard that they killed deer for tools and food,but why always deer?
they also killed other animals, but why deer most of the time?
was there some sort of benefit?
many books say,"  they do it for food and tools."{as I said before}
but they don't explain how and why they mostly use deer

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, @Whaley! What has your research shown you so far?
Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You might find
it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help]. You may improve your
question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask].
Without knowing what you read and where you read it, the question is difficult to answer.  Did they kill deer most of the time?

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason that hunters in the US & Europe mostly kill deer today: they're abundant, large enough to make good targets, and relatively easy to get within shooting distance - especially important when you are hunting with a bow rather than a rifle with telescopic sight.

Comment: @jamesqf much more important: easy to hunt, lots of meat, taste delicious.

Comment: Because they were hungry and wanted to eat, cold and wanted clothes, ,etc.  Because they were poor and wanted tools.

Answer (score 2):

People ate just about anything with legs for food in those days. Bears, badgers, foxes, voles & dormouse (they were a delicacy), mice - anything. That includes deer as well, my dear.

Comment: I don't think  that they ate ANYTHING that had legs though.Mostly, I suppose so.

Comment: @whaley no I'm pretty sure Jos means it literally. Kangaroos, Staffordshire terriers, chairs, ANYTHING.

Comment: @quant I believe you mean Canae Terrarum Flaeviae Caesariensis? ;) And Macropodae Terrarum Australis. :D

Comment: @quant  ...surplus progeny.